# Describe the column vectors $(a,x)^t$ that occur as the first column of an integer matrix A whose inverse is also an integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Describe the column vectors $(a,c)^t$ that occur as the first column of an integer matrix A whose inverse  is also an integer matrix.

I don't know what it let me do. Is it mean that I should find some properties of the vectors $(a,c)^t$. I have try as follows:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}   
    a & b \\
    c & d 
\end{array}
\right)*
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}   
    e & f \\
    g & h 
\end{array}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}   
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
then I got some integer equations:
$$
ae+bg=1\\
af+bh=0\\
ce+dg=1\\
cf+dh=0
$$
Should I solve these integer equations to get the properties of $(a,c)^t$?
What should I do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

What can you say about the determinant of such a matrix? Can $a$ and $c$ have a common factor $>1$?

Answer (score 1):

An explanation of @Ted Shifrin's Hint.

If the gcd of $a$ and $c$ is say $g$, $g>1$. Then $g$ $|$ det($A$). But since $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are both integer matrices, det($A$) $=1$ or $-1$. Thus $g=1$. Hence, $a$ and $c$ must be relatively prime.